# Ajuda com Javascript numeros

Tags: php, javascript

Estou com um projeto em Javascript no qual eu preciso add a numeros a uma testarea No exempro abaixo quando coloco numero 10 no input ele add o numero 10 na textarea e não o valor ex: https://jsfiddle.net/62zq0cxw/

O que eu preciso e que quando for digitado o valor na input ex: 10 ele criar as linhas com a contagem na textarea com um em cada linha

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Adicionar a quandidade de numeros do input no textarea](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/496621/adicionar-a-quandidade-de-numeros-do-input-no-textarea)